# Como podría de una venta, eliminar un producto en especifico y se actualice el total de la venta

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buen día, soy principiante el laravel, me interesa saber como puedo eliminar un producto de una venta y recalcular el nuevo total de la venta.
Use lo siguiente para crear una nueva venta.

```
 public function store(Request $request){
    $nueva = new Venta;

    $nueva->total = 0;
    $nueva->fecha = $request->get("fecha");
    $nueva->save();
    $productos = $request->get("productos_id");


    foreach ($productos as $producto) {
        $pId = $producto["id"];
        $pCantidad = $producto["cantidad"];
        $pro = Producto::find($pId);
        $suma = ($pCantidad * $pro->precio);
        $nueva->productos()->attach([$pro->id => ["cantidad" => $pCantidad, "subtotal" => $suma]]);
        $nueva->total += $suma;
    }
    $nueva->save();
    return $nueva->load("productos");
}
```

me gustaría averiguar como eliminarlo por método detach, ya que es una relacion muchos a muchos.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y trata de explicar mejor tu duda

Comment: Por ejemplo yo te preguntaría: ¿por qué `detach`?, ¿es una relación de muchos a muchos?

Comment: El metodo detach está explicado en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) de laravel. Necesitarías la id de la venta y la del producto. Prueba lo y agrega lo que hayas intentado a la pregunta.